# How to remove the trailing slash from end of the url

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In wordpress permalink setting. I have remove the trailing slash from the `"%postname%"`. Here it is after set to no trailing slash in setting:

```
example.com/%postname%
```

But the issue is for all locations urls its showing like this:

```
http://www.example.com/locations/in/bhopal
```

instead of this it's also removing the trailing slash from locations:

```
http://www.example.com/**locations**in/bhopal
```

Is there a way we can add trailing slash after location using `.htacess` or any other way?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, How are you adding the Locations Taxonomy, in that code you will see value set for rewrite parameter? Also see if this applies to your situation https://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2012/06/07/rewrite-endpoints-api/  I have removed end "/" from the urls but never faced issue with other urls on the site. So could be something specific to your Locations taxonomy generation code.